# Postgres return null values on function error/failure when casting

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, plpgsql

I am attempting to convert `text` values to `timestamp` values.
For the following table called **`a`**:

```
 id |         c1
----+--------------------
  1 | 03-03-2000
  2 | 01-01-2000
  3 | 12/4/1990
  4 | 12 Sept 2011
  5 | 12-1-1999 12:33:12
  6 | 24-04-89 2:33 am
```

I am attempting to perform a `select` with a **cast** as follows:

`select id, c1,`**`c1::timestamp`**`as c2 from a;`

This works correctly if there were only the first 5 rows, but for the 6th row where `c1` is `24-04-89 2:33 am` it throws the following error:

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "24-04-89 2:33 am"
>       HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

What I want is **`null` for those values which cannot not be casted** to timestamp instead of the command failing altogether. Like this:

```
 id |         c1         |         c2
----+--------------------+---------------------
  1 | 03-03-2000         | 2000-03-03 00:00:00
  2 | 01-01-2000         | 2000-01-01 00:00:00
  3 | 12/4/1990          | 1990-12-04 00:00:00
  4 | 12 Sept 2011       | 2011-09-12 00:00:00
  5 | 12-1-1999 12:33:12 | 1999-12-01 12:33:12
  6 | 24-04-89 2:33 am   | (null)
(6 rows)
```

---

**EDIT:**
Also, is there a generic way to implement this?  i.e.: (based on [klin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30800989/457447)) a plpgsql wrapper function that sets the value to `null` if the function it is wrapped around throws an error. 
For e.g.: a function `set_null_on_error` that can be used like this:

`select id, c1,`**`set_null_on_error(c1::timestamp)`**`as c2 from a;`

or

`select id, c1,`**`set_null_on_error(to_number(c1, '99'))`**`as c2 from a;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done by trapping an exception in a plpgsql function.

```
create or replace function my_to_timestamp(arg text)
returns timestamp language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    begin
        return arg::timestamp;
    exception when others then
        return null;
    end;
end $$;

select id, c1, my_to_timestamp(c1) as c2 from a;
```

---

**Trying to define a *generic* function.**

Assume that you defined a function `set_null_on_error(anyelement)`. Calling

```
select set_null_on_error('foo'::timestamp);
```

raises error **before** the function is executed.

You can try something like this:

```
create or replace function set_null_on_error(kind text, args anyarray)
returns anyelement language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    begin
        if kind = 'timestamp' then
            return args[1]::timestamp;
        elseif kind = 'number' then
            return to_number(args[1], args[2]);
        end if;
    exception when others then 
        return null;
    end;
end; $$;

select set_null_on_error('timestamp', array['2014-01-01']);
select set_null_on_error('number', array['1.22444', '9999D99']);
```

In my opinion such a solution is too complicated, quite inconvenient to use and generally might turn out to generate problems hard to debug.

Comment: is there any way other than writing a plpgsql function?

Comment: I do not think so. But God gave us plpgsql to use it.

Comment: can you please take a look at the edited part in the question, and let know if that is achievable?

Comment: That is not achievable because a plpgsql function must have explicit defined type of its arguments and result.

Comment: I just discovered that you can define the types to be polymorphic - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC