# POSTGRES - evaluate (sub)expression error as NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms

I have sensor data in a Postgres table `measurements` with columns `id`, `timestamp`, `s0`, `s1`, `s2`, ...

Besides, there is an index on columns `(id, timestamp)`. I want to allow for dynamic math expressions (in the example below: `sin(s3)*0.1000/s5`) for calculation of derived values.

```
SELECT
  timestamp,
  trunc((sin(s3) * 0.1000/s5)::numeric, 3) AS "calculated"
FROM measurements
WHERE id = 42
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10000;
```

Obviously, this is prone to a "division by zero" error which will make the query fail. Is there a way to catch this error and return e.g. `NULL` for the calculated value where the error would occur?

Inspired by

- [Postgres return null values on function error/failure when casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800140/postgres-return-null-values-on-function-error-failure-when-casting?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [Store a formula in a table and use the formula in a function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33894/store-a-formula-in-a-table-and-use-the-formula-in-a-function)

I already tried defining a `postgres` function `eval_numeric(sensors int[], formula text)` that parses the formula and returns `NULL` on exception. The third row of the SQL statement above now reads

```
trunc(eval_numeric(ARRAY[s3,s5],'sin(var1)*0.1/var2'), 3) AS "calculated"
```

This gives the desired behavior but execution time as reported by `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` increases by a factor of 20 (~20ms -> ~400ms). Any other ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

The dynamic expression to be evaluated stems from a web application user. So the formula above is only an example (might require checking for negative argument to square root). I'd rather have a generic error checking possibility and would prefer not having logic in the math expression. This would be easier for the end user and I could validate the allowed math e.g. with a math parser thereby preventing SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the expression to this?

```
SELECT timestamp,
       trunc((sin(s3) * 0.1000/nullif(s5, 0))::numeric, 3) AS "calculated",
FROM measurements
WHERE id = 42
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10000;
```

This is the simplest way to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast. This seems to be feasible and is fast. I'd prefer not having logic in the math expression. I'll update my question with respect to this. But maybe this is another problem. I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    timestamp,
    CASE WHEN s5 != 0
         THEN trunc((sin(s3) * 0.1000/s5)::numeric, 3)
         ELSE NULL AS "calculated",
FROM measurements
WHERE id = 42
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10000;
```

This has the potential benefit that you may replace the value with anything you want, including `NULL`.

Another option, if you don't care about rows which would have triggered a divide by zero, would be to just add the check on `s5` to the `WHERE` clause and filter off those rows before the division happens.